# Laravel: Getting Data from another Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a drop down, and on this drop down I want to fill it with the data I have on the other database table.

**P.S** - My dropdown and its other form inputs have its own database table namely ***tbl_movies*** , and on the dropdown itself which I want to fill in the data o the database table namely ***tbl_clients*** .

Should I make a relationship or what not? Idk sorry help and guide me pls

I have this dropdown form and how should I fill it with data on the other table ?

```
 {{Form::select('client', null,
                    ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Status...'])}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get your data from table and Pass data from your controller to view**

```
$data['movies'] = Movies::pluck('name','id');
return view('viewPageName',$data); // pass your data to view page from controller
```

**On your view file instead of your select use this**

```
{{Form::select('client', $movies,
                ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Status...'])}}
```

Hope this idea will help you!

Comment: wait  `$data['movies'] = Movies::pluck('name','id');`  how can I pass it to **view** ? where and how? anywhere? should i use @php @endphp or what?

Comment: where should I put it to controller? store or what?

Comment: yeah sir, but which public function should I code? is it okay on the public function index?

Comment: why is it  **$movies** instead of **$data** ?

Comment: If you are access your view file from index() then just put the code before you calling the return view .  just Put the code before while you calling the view page

Comment: Dear i think you are not familier with laravel at all. I recommanded to you study from documentation

Comment: sir, it has an error **Undefined variable: clients** sorry please help me i need to finish this :(

Comment: i followed your steps sir but error occurd :( **Undefined variable: clients** it is the same process as yours as i created new project

Comment: {{Form::select('client', $movies,
                ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Status...'])}}

i put the $movies why you are trying to access with $clients. Just put $movies instead of $client

Comment: are you success to do that?

Comment: Thank you  Dear :)

Comment: sir please help me lastly this real quick how can I validate a unique data..  how can i make this unique   `'client_code' => 'required',`  .. please help I forgot to make it unique on migrating database now i regret it how can i make it unique on controller side

Comment: On your Store function on controller just put this code 'client_code' => ['required','unique:tableName'],,

Comment: if I coded it to the update why it is giving me an error sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184458/discussion-between-md-jubair-mizan-and-summer-winter).

Comment: I will post another question sir will you answer it?